# Use tree component from syncfusion with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, syncfusion

I am working on a project and I already use Material UI. Recently, I have encountered an issue finding a checkboxes tree in Material UI and I've found it in Syncfusion. Would it be okay if I imported only the tree component from Syncfusion and use it within my project which already uses Material UI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install [syncfusion/ej2-react-navigations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@syncfusion/ej2-react-navigations) package to use EJ2 TreeView component in your react project.

Refer to the following UG and demo links for getting started with EJ2 React TreeView component.

UG:  https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/treeview/getting-started/

Demo: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/demos/#/material/treeview/check-box

API: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/api/treeview/